# How to get the updated state value in intersection observer React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, intersection-observer

I have been struggling to find the solution to this problem for ages. If you have the answer, I would appreciate it. I have a component in which I want to use Intersection Observer. When a certain element is visible in the viewport, the function will be called to do something. But the problem is, when that function is called, you don't have the most updated state values in that function. Let me show it to you with a code example.

Intersection Observer

```
 const [someState,setSomeState] =useState(someVal)

 useEffect(() => {
    if (!isInfinite || !infiniteLoadingRef || !infiniteLoadingRef.current)
      return;
    const options = {
      root: null,
      rootMargin: "0px",
      threshold: 0,
    };
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleObserver, options);
    observer.observe(infiniteLoadingRef.current);
  }, [infiniteLoadingRef]);
```

The function that gets called when a certain element is visible in the viewport

```
 const handleObserver = (entries: any, observer: any) => {
    if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
      console.log(someState);
    }
  };
```

We have a state called `someState` and for some reason, that state gets updated and the entire component rerendered. Only after `someState` value changed, the handleObserver will be called. I am using someState inside that handleObserver and I don't get the most updated state's value. How do I get the most updated someState value in handleObserver? I tried putting `someState` as a dependency in my `useEffect`, but I got into an infinite loop. Please help me figure out this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `useCallback`. It should keep the actual `someState` inside `handleObserver`:

```
const handleObserver = useCallback((entries: any, observer: any) => {
  if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
    console.log(someState);
  }
}, [someState]);
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks